# load image inside JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, image, function, canvas, html5-canvas

i have function to get image pixels color

```
function getImage(imgsrc){
    var img = $( "<img>", {
        src: imgsrc
    });
    var imageMap = new Object();
    img.load(function() {
        var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0].getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        for(var i = 0;i < this.width;i++){
            imageMap[i] = new Object();
            for(var j = 0;j < this.width;j++){
                var pixelData = canvas.getImageData(i, j, 1, 1).data;
                imageMap[i][j] = rgbToHex(pixelData[0],pixelData[1],pixelData[2]);
            }
        }
            console.log(imageMap[40][40]);
    });
    console.log(imageMap[40][40]);
    return imageMap;
}
```

but it return undefined(it print 2nd console.log first)
what's wrong?

thx.

Comment: It's 'cause the `load` is asynchronous. You can't `return` from an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is returning `undefined` because `load` is asynchronous. `getImage` is trying to return something before `load` finished loading.

You'll need to pass a callback to execute when the image has loaded, to `getImage`:

```
function getImage(imgsrc, callback){
    var img = $( "<img>", {
        src: imgsrc
    });
    var imageMap = new Object();
    img.load(function() {
        var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0].getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
        for(var i = 0;i < this.width;i++){
            imageMap[i] = new Object();
            for(var j = 0;j < this.width;j++){
                var pixelData = canvas.getImageData(i, j, 1, 1).data;
                imageMap[i][j] = rgbToHex(pixelData[0],pixelData[1],pixelData[2]);
            }
        }
        console.log(imageMap[40][40]);
        callback(imageMap)
    });
}
```

Then you just call the function like this:

```
getImage("http://some.src.jpg", function(imageMap){
    // Do stuff with imageMap here;
});
```

Of course, you can also define the callback elsewhere:

```
var myCallback = function(imageMap){
    // Do stuff with imageMap here;
};

getImage("http://some.src.jpg", myCallback);
```

Answer (score 3):

Now that promises <strike>starts to get</strike> [have] wide support you can do this instead:

```js
// Define a common load function:
function loadImage(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() { resolve(this) };
    img.onerror = img.onabort = function() { reject("Error loading image") };
    img.src = url;
  })
}

// Usage:
loadImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynBVu.gif").then(function(image) {

  // Use the `image` here
  document.body.appendChild(image);

})
```

The promise will take the callback, states etc. internally. <strike>IE will get support in next version</strike> (there exists [polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) for it).

Comment: This is the most accurate answer now, since all current browsers [support Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

[**jQuery.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous, meaning the code will continue while it goes of working away.

If you want to process the `imagemap`, one option could be to pass a callback you execute ones the `imagemap` is populated, similar to:

```
function yourCallback(imageMap){
// ...process imageMap;
}

function getImage(imgsrc, yourCallback) {
    var img = $("<img>", {
        src: imgsrc
    });
    var imageMap = new Object();
    img.load(function () {
        var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0].getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = this.width;
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.drawImage(this, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
            imageMap[i] = new Object();
            for (var j = 0; j < this.width; j++) {
                var pixelData = canvas.getImageData(i, j, 1, 1).data;
                imageMap[i][j] = rgbToHex(pixelData[0], pixelData[1], pixelData[2]);
            }
        }

        yourCallback(imageMap);
    });
}

getImage(imgsrc,yourCallback);
```