# Rescaling and cropping image at page load with angular directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a directive that rescale and crop an image depending on its height and width.

```
angular.module('starter.directives', ['starter.controllers']).directive('styleImage', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function preLink(scope, elem, attr) {
        elem.on('load', function () {
            styleImage(elem[0])
        });
    }
};
```

})

which styleImage function gets the elements width and height and rescale and crop it.
And I call the directive as follow:

```
<img ng-src="{{user.image_path }}" class="user-image" style-image
                             id="{{'user'+user.user_id}}">
```

Everything is OK except when I load the page it takes a few second  in order for the directive to rescale and crop the image. So at first the images appears with their initial width and size. 
Is it possible that I force the directive runs before the image is load? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sequence of events in Angular is

1- `Routes` detect the URL requested via browser.

2- `Http request` to get the view templateUrl declared in your routing.

3- `View` rendered on the page.

4- `directives` on the view firing

So it's the normal behavior to see the image then to see it cropped,

I think the solution is to use template in your directive I mean something like this

**HTML**

```
<style-image my-src='user.image_path'></style-image>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('starter.directives', ['starter.controllers']).directive('styleImage', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope{
    mySrc:"="
  },
  link: function preLink(scope, elem, attr) {
    var img= document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src',scope.mySrc)
    styleImage(img)
    elem.append(img);
   }
 };
})
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a lot. But there is another problem. Some of the images won't appear and when I check chromes network, all other images initiator is directive.js (which the directive is in) and the image that won't appear is "other". Do you have any idea why this happen?

Comment: My assumption is that the directive  runs before the image is transfered. Is it the case? if so how can I fix it?

Comment: You can request the images inside link function in the directive

Comment: Can you tell me how it can be done? I couldn't find anything that could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. With the help of this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28405879/load-image-inside-javascript-function#28423479] I found a workaround

Comment: I am sorry for being late .. glad to hear that you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

try this `below links`

[Link](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop)

[link1](http://angular-js.in/ngimgcrop/)

Comment: That is not what I want. I want rescale and image automatically. And I don't have problem with rescaling and cropping. The problem is with the time of execution